# Eclipse / Maven: Best approach for working with re-usable libraries and interdependent projects?

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I'm just getting back to the Java/Eclipse world after a long stint in the .NET world. I'm also somewhat new to Maven and getting the hang of it, but have a bit of a dilemma ...

I'm currently working on a couple of Spring-Boot services.  Both of these depend on new libraries I developed, which I plan to re-use extensively in other projects as well.

I started off setting up 3 eclipse projects as modules under an empty POM-based parent for convenience:

Parent POM

1. Service1 POM
2. LibB POM
3. LibA POM

Where LibB depends on LibA and Service1 depends on both LibA and LibB.

However, then came a requirement for Service2, which would depend on LibA.

So, I decided to get rid of the parent POM and make Service1, LibA, LibB and now Service2 independent eclipse/maven projects.  I'm thinking this will allow me to manage them independently in Git as well.

I tried defining in-project repositories where I could include the LibA and LibB jars in Servcie1, Servcie2 and LibB (since LibB depends on LibA).  However, eclipse/maven didn't seem to pick up on this... instead of picking up the jars, it seems to be referencing the lib projects directly (see screenshot) below.

What is the best approach here?

[image]

**cx-config-service POM:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<groupId>com.esi.cx</groupId>
<artifactId>cx-config-service</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Leaving out irrelevant dependencies for brevity ... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.esi.cx</groupId>
        <artifactId>cx-utility</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.esi.cx</groupId>
        <artifactId>cx-genesys</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**cx-genesys POM:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.esi.cx</groupId>
<artifactId>cx-genesys</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo</id>
        <name>repo</name>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Leaving out irrelevant dependencies for brevity ... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.esi.cx</groupId>
        <artifactId>cx-utility</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

**cx-utility POM:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.esi.cx</groupId>
<artifactId>cx-utility</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Leaving out irrelevant dependencies for brevity ... -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you add more details at your question. For example can you show us the pom.xml of cx-config-service? I think that you have to add LibA and LibB like dependencies and not like modules

Comment: Eclipse automatically uses project links instead of JAR if the project coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version) matches the dependency ones. That is usually the approach you want, as if you modify a class of your library project, the other project depending on it will automatically "see" the change

Comment: Thanks guys, I added my POMs for reference.